# Typescript: dependency doesn't seem to be fulfiled

Tags: typescript, npm

Compiling an Angular project, I'm getting an error from a package I installed with NPM:

> node_modules/astrocite-ris/index.d.ts:36:39 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'CSL'.

The package, [Astrocite](https://github.com/dsifford/astrocite), includes the subpackage astrocite-ris. I've included it in the package.json as `"astrocite": "^0.16.4",` and imported it into a service with:

```
import { parse } from 'astrocite-ris';
```

VSCode shows the error in the index.d.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typings for `astrocite-ris` seem a bit iffy. The package is written in TypeScript, but the typings come from a manually written 3-year old `index.d.ts`. When dealing with type errors in packages themselves, you can choose to disable type checking inside `node_modules` by adding `"skipLibCheck": false` to the `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck)). However, in this case, you can also fix the problem by including

```
import 'csl-json'
```

in one of your source files, as this will declare the global `CSL` namespace. It's also a good idea to do an `npm i -D csl-json` to explicitly include the package in your dev-dependencies. Utimately, the problem will need to be fixed by the developer of `astrocite-ris` though, so you might want to open an issue in https://github.com/dsifford/astrocite.

Comment: Thank you! There's a work around by using `import { ris } from 'astrocite';` and then using `ris.parse`. I will write an issue or a pull request over there